Weird result on using html2canvas
I'm trying to take a screenshot of my vue app using html2canvas. My code is running correctly but my screenshot have weird padding/margin on the text.
"vue": "^3.4.21"
"html2canvas": "^1.4.1"

Here's my code:
html2canvas(document.body, {
      width: 400,
      height: 200,
    }).then((canvas) => {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    });

What the part screenshot look like in my app
Result
I'm using brave, but same issue on safari and chrome.

"I'm using brave, but same issue on safari and chrome." So the problem is not html2canvas?

Provide the relevant code as well to achieve a minimal reproducible issue

Html2canvas « is only able to render correctly properties that it understands, meaning there are many CSS properties which do not work. For a full list of supported CSS properties, check out the supported features page.«

https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation

This is the supported features page: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/features/
